# Empty boundary of a p-chain

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Definition: A $p$-cycle is a $p$-chain with empty boundary: suppose that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism from $C_{p}$ to $C_{p-1}$. Then,$\forall \alpha \in C_{p}, \phi(\alpha) = e_{+} \in C_{p-1}$.

[Persistent Homology: An Introduction and a New Text Representation for Natural Language Processing](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jerryzhu/pub/homology.pdf)

In the paper the author provides an example of an empty boundary

[image]

I understand that a if boundary which maps elements in a $C_{p}$ group to the identity element in $C_{p-1}$, then the elements in $C_{p}$ are $p$-chains with empty boundary.

Can someone help me to understand why this is so? - the image on the left is an example of a 1 - cycle.

Comment: It just means no boundary. That is, this is a $p$-chain which is not a boundary of another chain. Say you have a solid triangle (a $2$-chain), the $1$-cycle is its three sides. The perimeter has no boundary.

Comment: @Everiana What does perimeter means here?

Comment: The boundary of a $p$-chain $\alpha$ is a $(p-1)$ chain $\beta$ such that $\partial\alpha=\beta$, where $\partial:C_p\to C_{p-1}$ is a boundary operator. If it has no boundary means $\alpha$ is closed, i.e. $\partial\alpha=0$. I think in your notation (which seems nonstandard), $\partial=\phi$ and $0\equiv e_+$. Looking at the right diagram, the vertical line on the right is a 1-chain which has two boundaries (red dots). The triangle on the left is a 1-chain that has no boundary (since the boundary would be a 0-chain, but it forms a loop so no point along it is a boundary.

Comment: @Everiana I understand it algebraically. But if you would help me to understand how to reconcile this formalism with the above edited OP, I'd be appreciative. Put it as an answer and I will accept it with an upvote together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the notes you attached, the definition of a $p$-cycle is in Definition 18. Given a $p$-chain $\alpha$, its boundary is a $(p-1)$-chain $\beta$ such that $\partial\alpha=\beta$, where $\partial:C_p\to C_{p-1}$ is a boundary operator. Consequently, $\alpha$ has *no boundary* if $\partial\alpha=0$, where $0$ is the identity element of $C_{p-1}$ (we call it zero since in many contexts of homology theory, the operation of the group element is in additive notation).

The simplest way to make this intuition precise is to use "barycentric coordinates" of $R^d$, i.e. you label simplexes by its vertices as points in $R^d$. For our purposes let us use the diagram above.

For the left diagram, we have a 1-cycle (which is an "empty" triangle with no interior). Call this cycle $\alpha=(x_0x_1x_2)$ where $x_j$ label vertices. Note that its edges are also 1-chains, i.e. $(x_0x_1),(x_1x_2),(x_2x_0)\in C_1$. The boundary operator acting on an edge, for example $(x_1x_2)$, gives the two boundary "points", namely $x_2-x_1$. You could actually use $+$ instead of minus since following this paper, it is the sum modulo 2 ($+_2$), as in Definition 17. Following this, you can show that
$$\partial(x_0x_1x_2)=x_0-x_1+x_1-x_2+x_2-x_0 = 0\,.$$
This formalizes the intuition that "a closed loop has no boundary". Similarly, on the right diagram, the straight vertical right edge has two boundary points (in red) because of the definition above. This formalizes the idea that a finite line segment has two boundaries (namely, its endpoints).

Comment: So am I correct to say that an empty boundary of a $p$-chain consists only of their respective edges without the vertices "connecting" the edges?

Comment: @Mathematicing, yes and in fact if you account for the definition of $\partial(x_0x_1)=x_1+_2x_0$, then it follows that the points on the respective edges cancels each other out when the edges form a loop (like the triangle above).

Comment: And this is the clarification that I was looking for. 'Empty' boundary has been thrown around but no definition to what it means have been supplied by the author.